# Given equal surface area to volume ratios, which cools faster?

Tags: thermodynamics

Let's say you have two cylinders one flatter and one longer, both having equal surface area and both having equal volume. Which will arrive at the surrounding temperature first? Assume that the method of cooling doesn't benefit either shape.

The dimensions are r = 1.20214, h = 5.944 and r = 2.13946, h = 1.877

This provides two cylinders with same volumes and surface areas. Quite interesting. Also the ratio of surface area to volume is 54/27 or exactly 2. Just for funzies.

For any volume and surface area there are always two cylinders that will fit that volume-surface area combo.

Reason why:
I simply just wanted to figure out how long I should leave my soda in the freezer and how I would calculate that. Then I got sidetracked thinking about this question.

Comment: Wait a minute. Same volume and same surface area and both cylinders but different dimensions?

Comment: Ah I know I was quite confused for a second as well. I will post the dimensions.

Comment: For the case of minimum surface area, the two solutions must be the same?

Comment: Oh, so they're not "equal". Only "approximately" equal. This has gone from a physics problem to an engineering problem. BTW, care to post the mathematical proof of the last statement?

Comment: @OscarBravo If $V/S=Q$ then $1/2Q=1/R+1/H$ , so there should be plenty of $R,H$ combinations satisfying a given $Q$, is it not?

Comment: As a rule of thumb I'd say, the closer to a sphere, the slower it cools, i.e. compared to a compact one both, a long skinny one or a super flat one will cool faster as the heat has a shorter distance to the surface. If the shapes are very similar of course, you'd have to solve the heat equations as stated by @YoA

Comment: @mikuszefski For a fixed area, the possible values of $r$ and $h$ give a curve $r(r+h)=A$. For a fixed volume, there is $r^2h=V$. Depending on the values of $A, V$,  the two curves can intersect 0 or 2 times. So, indeed, it is possible to have up to two different cylinders with the same Volume and Area but different radius and height. I wouldn't have thought it...

Comment: @mikuszefski Ya I thought that was pretty cool when I figured that out too. Wanna know something else cool?!?! Found that the diameter of a circle and the edge of a cube, if the same, will force the volume to surface area ratios of the cube/sphere to be the same. Boom mind blown.

Comment: I assume that this is a heat conduction problem, and the boundary condition is fixed low temperature over the entire surface of each cylinder, correct?

Comment: @ChesterMiller According to the recent edit this stemmed from thoughts on cooling a can of soda.  The ideal calculation using constant surface temperature isn't going to capture everything since the heat distribution in the can would play a role.

Comment: @JMac it was just a thought experiment. YoA answered my question perfectly. It's what I originally thought. The actual shape of the object effects heat dissipation. Even for two items of same volume and surface area. I'm not about to start doing some differentials to actually calculate the time required.

Comment: @AARon I agree.  I understand what Chester was getting at though.  Often times in heat transfer problems like this you are given the boundary condition of the surface of the can and determine the heat transfer out from that (i.e. assumed steady state heat transfer).  It is the transient effects that make the geometry important.

Comment: @OscarBravo: or one time;  $a = r(r + h)$ and $b = r^2 h$ implies a cubic in $r$ from equating $h$ terms, $b/r^2 = a/r - r$ gives $r^3 - a r + b= 0.$ Taking a derivative of the LHS gives $r=\pm\sqrt{a/3}$ as local minima/maxima, it's possible for these to coincide with the positive 0 if $b = \sqrt{4/27} a^{3/2}$. But it has at most 3 roots and with that local maximum at negative $x$ when it does have 3 roots one must be at negative $r$, so at most 2 positive roots.

Comment: @JMac You will still have a heat distribution in the cylinder even if the surface temperature is constant.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Assuming constant surface temperature is assuming that the heat distribution in the cylinder doesn't effect the surface temperature.  That's just a terrible assumption in this case because the can has no way to maintain constant surface temperature.  It would only model the steady state, which would require a heat input in the can equal to what is being lost to the freezer (which the can has no mechanism to provide).  Constant temperature is steady state, and steady state can't tell you which cools faster during the whole cooling event.

Comment: @JMac That's not what I get out of the OPs original question.

Comment: @CRDrost: Thanks for the formal derivation! I sketched the curves and (in the +ve x-y quadrant) slid them around to see how they intersected.. You get  two reversed "J" shapes with different curvature so they either don't meet at all (0 intersects), cross over twice, or - in one precise case - just touch at a single point. I was quite surprised by this; intuitively, I would've guessed that for a given $V$ and $A$, a cylinder must have a unique $r$ and $h$. You learn something every day...

Answer (score 2):

If we can assume that there is no significant loss of energy due to radiation (which I'm not sure we can):

I think that aside from surface area you need to take into account the rate at which heat diffuses to the surface of the object.

The heat flux given by Fourier's law of thermal conduction:
$$q=-k\frac{dT}{dx}$$

where q is the heat flux density and k is the conductivity of the material. 
The derivative on the RHS is a measure of the **local** difference in temperature, i.e. the difference between the surface of the object and the outside air (assuming that there is air or some other material to 'accept' the heat energy).

My point is that the surface temperature is not necessarily equal for both objects, since heat must be conducted from the internals of the object to the surface, and therefore the heat flux density is not equal.

You must solve the 3D heat equation for each object with the appropriate boundary conditions.

Comment: So I think I get what you're saying. Even though they have the same volume and therefore quanity of heat, and even though the area exposed is identical, the way the heat radiates to the surface of the shape determines the loss rate.

Comment: Yes, but just to clarify: heat conduction towards the surface is modeled by the heat equation (not sure if 'radiates' is the proper wording)

Comment: I think this sheds some light into the issue here.  It depends on what you assume the heat source to be.  Often times in (at least engineering) heat transfer we would be given a surface temperature for the cylinders; so this wouldn't change it a whole lot.  If you were doing a thorough analysis of say a fluid in the cylinder; it would make the difference.

Answer (score 2):

In the squat lumpy piece, heat has to move further to reach a surface and be conducted away. In the long skinny one you can think of the the material all being closer to the surface, no more than 0.6 away from a surface, and it will cool faster.